# How to open serial port in linux without changing any pin?

Tags: linux, serial-port, posix

Posix requires changing RTS pin on port opening. I want a way to avoid it.

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you want to do with RTS? How the standard requires to change it and why?

Comment: I want leave rts without changing during port opening

Comment: Just to clarify - in Linux at least, calling open("/dev/ttyUSB0", os.RDWR) makes both the RTS and the DTR lines go up in the serial port. After the port has been opened, RTS can be set to low again by calling ioctl. However, the question is - how to open the device without setting RTS high even momentarily?

Comment: Have you tried `stty` (before opening the port)? In particular one or more of these control settings: `clocal -crtscts -cdtrdsr`. Alternate control settings (found those in AIX documentation): `-cdxon -ctsxon -dtrxoff -rtsxoff`.

Comment: `stty` requires redirecting the output to the terminal to have any effects (obviously) and doing `stty clocal > /dev/ttyUSB0` obviously opens the serial port before doing the action. So, `stty` will also cause the RTS line to go high, atleast momentarily.

Comment: Does it have to be posix? Disabling flow control with CRTSCTS (termios(3)) might do the trick, otherwise.

Comment: Calling termios requires getting an fd, which requires an open, which toggles the state of RTS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the same problem, I'd give it a try by patching the `ftdi_sio` kernel driver. You just need to uncomment a small piece of code in `ftdi_dtr_rts()` like this:

```
static void ftdi_dtr_rts(struct usb_serial_port *port, int on) {
    ...
    /* drop RTS and DTR */
    if (on)
        set_mctrl(port, TIOCM_DTR /*| TIOCM_RTS*/);    // <<-- HERE
    else
        clear_mctrl(port, TIOCM_DTR /*| TIOCM_RTS*/);  // <<-- and HERE
}
```

and the RTS handshake line is not longer changed upon `open()` call.
Note, that the uart than might not longer working with RTS/CTS hardware handshake, as long as your modified kernel driver is loaded. But you can still control the state of the RTS handshake line manually by calling e.g.:

```
    int opins = TIOCM_RTS;
    ioctl(tty_fd, TIOCMBIC, &opins);
```

I'd tested this with the `Ctrl+A+G` command of picocom 2.3a, running Kubuntu 16.04 64 bit and [Ftdi FT2232H](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT2232H.htm) based usb uart adapter.

You might find more details on this topic [here](https://github.com/npat-efault/picocom/blob/master/lowerrts.md).

Comment: Could you check how O_NONBLOCK option interferes with it?

Comment: Checking [picocom.c](https://github.com/npat-efault/picocom/blob/master/picocom.c), it uses `O_NONBLOCK`: `tty_fd = open(opts.port, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK | O_NOCTTY);` and it behaves as described above.

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea why you'd want to do this, but this can be done pretty easily by modifying the linux kernel driver for your serial console so it doesn't toggle RTS.  For example, for the 8250-series driver in `drivers/tty/serial/8250/` you could change every write to the MCR register (UART_MCR) to ensure that bit 1 (mask is UART_MCR_RTS) is never set.

Since it's abstracted away in userspace, you're out of luck if you want to do this without modifying the kernel driver.

Comment: "Not possible without modifying the kernel" is a perfectly good answer. Thank you.

Comment: "I have no idea why you'd want to do this" -> it's very common for embedded bootloaders to have RTS connected to the reset pin and DTR connected to the bootloader select pin (or vice versa). If the reset pin is toggled, even for a fraction of a microsecond, the chip will reset. This means that it isn't easy to use the control lines for this purpose if you're also using the serial port for general communication with the device... not without disconnecting the control lines first :(

Comment: I see, it's sort of hijacking the control flow line to reset into a programming state right before serial data is sent.  Convenient, at least until design changes from having a tiny microcontroller to use a quad-core SoC running Linux and the hardware engineer doesn't bother to consult anyone on changes required to the programming model.

Comment: @cha5on Yeah, it's definitely a hack, better to have a real upload protocol that doesn't interfere with the serial lines, unfortunately in the real world many devices just expose a USB port with a serial interface behind that does just that, so you need to either work with that or spend time modding the device (or throw it away).

Answer (score 3):

A change in the DTR pin can be (eventually) avoided using the command line

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -hupcl
```

This has the effect of making DTR turn on; and subsequently when the port is opened and closed, DTR is not affected.

Source: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9695/disable-dtr-on-ttyusb0/27706#27706

And there is code there to do the same thing from python via `termios`, this can be done before opening the port via pyserial:

```
import termios

path = '/dev/ttyACM0'

# Disable reset after hangup
with open(path) as f:
    attrs = termios.tcgetattr(f)
    attrs[2] = attrs[2] & ~termios.HUPCL
    termios.tcsetattr(f, termios.TCSAFLUSH, attrs)
```

The OP was running this on a Raspberry Pi, but I just tried it on Linux Mint on x86_64, it worked. I don't know how RTS is affected.

The reason I find this useful, is for communication with an Arduino Nano - which has a USB-> serial chip on board - and normally the Arduino gets reset every time you open the serial port from linux (rising edge of DTR causes reset).  For some applications, this is not a problem, but it's clearly useful to avoid this for other applications, and it's not so easy to remove that tiny capacitor from the Arduino which connects DTR to reset.

You will still get a single reset when the stty command is executed (after plugging in the USB cable). But at least you can then keep opening and closing the serial port after that without further resets.

Answer (score 0):

I found my way here looking for a solution to the same problem. My challenge is that I'm working with a variety of pre-existing software, and I was not looking forward to patching everything individually.

I put together an `LD_PRELOAD`-able library that automatically sets RTS low after opening a serial port; you can find it at https://github.com/larsks/force_rts/. Using it looks like this:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/force_rts.so
export FORCE_RTS_DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyS0"
...some command here...
```

For example, I'm using `rigctl` to control a radio attached to my computer; previously, running any `rigctl` command would trigger PTT on the radio and cause it to start transmitting.

With the library injected using `LD_PRELOAD`, I can run the `rigctl` commands without impacting the PTT control.

Comment: You solution creates a spike on RTS.

Comment: That's correct. There's no way around that without patching the kernel. For my use case (ham radio) this is inconsequential and unnoticeable, and it's much easier than either patching the kernel or patching multiple pieces of software to perform the same operation performed by this library.

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Answer (score -3):

calling `fopen("/dev/ACM0", "r")` doesn't require you do do anything:) You may not receive the data you expect though.

Comment: this call will change RTS pin. I need avoid it.