# What are the unwanted side effects of open in ioctl?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix, ioctl

According to `man ioctl`, opening file descriptors with `open` may cause unwanted side-effects. The manual also states that opening with `O_NONBLOCK` solves those unwanted issues but I can't seem to find what's the reason for that, nor what are the actual side-effects. Can someone shed light into that? With `ioctl` is it always possible and equivalent* to open file descriptors with `O_NONBLOCK`?

> **NOTES** (from `man ioctl`)
>
> In order to use this call, one needs an open file descriptor.  Often the open(2) call has unwanted side effects, that can be avoided
>   under Linux by giving it the O_NONBLOCK flag.

(* I am aware of what `O_NONBLOCK` implies, but I don't know if that affects `ioctl` calls the same way it affects other syscalls. My program, which uses `ioctl` to write and read from an SPI bus, works perfectly with that flag enabled.)

Comment: As ioctls are mean to accesse device-specific features, it is impossible to tell without knowing what you are talking about. Btw. this is similar for `opne` itself.

Comment: Serial ports are probably the main problem area. Traditionally, opening the tty device sends a signal that is detectable by the device at the other end of the serial cable. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5090451/2404501) for an example discussion (in which the conclusion was not that `O_NONBLOCK` would prevent it, but that there is no way to prevent it!)

Comment: Another idea that just came to mind is removable storage. If you want to open `/dev/cdrom` to call the eject ioctl, you might need to specify `O_NONBLOCK` to prevent it trying to read a disc? And/or something similar for tapes and floppies? These are unverified guesses though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious place to look for the answer would be the [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) man page, which, under the heading for `O_NONBLOCK`, says:

> When possible, the file is opened in nonblocking mode.
>     Neither the open() nor any subsequent operations on the file
>     descriptor which is returned will cause the calling process to
>     wait.
>
> [...]
>
> For the handling of FIFOs (named pipes), see also [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html).
>     For a discussion of the effect of O_NONBLOCK in conjunction
>     with mandatory file locks and with file leases, see [fcntl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html).

OK, that wasn't very informative, but let's follow the links and see what the manual pages for fifo(7) and fcntl(2) say:

> Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.
>
> A process can open a FIFO in nonblocking mode.  In this case, opening
>     for read-only will succeed even if no-one has opened on the write
>     side yet and opening for write-only will fail with ENXIO (no such
>     device or address) unless the other end has already been opened.
>
> Under Linux, opening a FIFO for read and write will succeed both in
>     blocking and nonblocking mode.  POSIX leaves this behavior undefined.

So here's at least one "unwanted side effect": even just trying to open a FIFO may block, unless you pass `O_NONBLOCK` to the `open()` call (and open it for reading).

What about fcntl, then?  As the open(2) man page notes, the sections to look under are those title "Mandatory locking" and "File leases".  It *seems* to me that mandatory locks, in this case, are a red herring, though — they only cause blocking when one tries to actually read from or write to the file:

> If a process tries to perform an incompatible
>     access (e.g., read(2) or write(2)) on a file region that has an
>     incompatible mandatory lock, then the result depends upon whether the
>     O_NONBLOCK flag is enabled for its open file description.  If the
>     O_NONBLOCK flag is not enabled, then the system call is blocked until
>     the lock is removed or converted to a mode that is compatible with
>     the access.

What about leases, then?

> When a process (the "lease breaker") performs an open(2) or
>     truncate(2) that conflicts with a lease established via F_SETLEASE,
>     the system call is blocked by the kernel and the kernel notifies the
>     lease holder by sending it a signal (SIGIO by default). [...]
>
> Once the lease has been voluntarily or forcibly removed or
>     downgraded, and assuming the lease breaker has not unblocked its
>     system call, the kernel permits the lease breaker's system call to
>     proceed.
>
> [...]  If
>     the lease breaker specifies the O_NONBLOCK flag when calling open(2),
>     then the call immediately fails with the error EWOULDBLOCK, but the
>     other steps still occur as described above.

OK, so that's another unwanted side effect: if the file you're trying to open has a lease on it, the `open()` call may block until the lease holder has released the lease.

In both cases, the "unwanted side effect" avoided by passing `O_NONBLOCK` to `open()` is, unsurprisingly, the `open()` call itself blocking until some other process has done something.  If there are any *other* kinds of side effects that the man page you cite refers to, I'm not aware of them.

Answer (score 1):

From *Linux System Programming, 2nd Edition*, by R. Love (emphasis mine):

> O_NONBLOCK
>   If possible, the file will be opened in nonblocking mode. **Neither the
>   open() call,
>   *nor any other operation* will cause the process to block (sleep) on the I/O.
>   This
>   behaviour may be defined only for FIFOs.**
>
> Sometimes, programmers do not want a call to read() to block when there is
>   no data
>   available. Instead, they prefer that the call return immediately,
>   indicating that no data
>   is available. This is called nonblocking I/O; it allows applications to
>   perform I/O, potentially
>   on multiple files, without ever blocking, and thus missing data available in
>   another file.
>
> Consequently, an additional errno value is worth checking: EAGAIN.

See [this thread](https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2014-February/009828.html) on the kernel mailing list.